# store objectID in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

If I wanted to store a list of objectsID's of different entities in CoreData what would the data type be for the objectID so I could use it in an NSFetchRequest to later retrive the Entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not store NSManagedObjectID, but you can store the object's URI representation, and use that to retrieve the object id using NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's  managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation: method. Since you seem to want a list, i would save it in a new entity and store the necessary information to identify the id and the entity name it belongs to, among other relevant information.